# What is meaning of "normalization" in reference to geocoding?

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, geospatial

What is meaning of "normalization" in reference to geocoding? I understand that geocoding is the trasnformation of string address to latitude and longitude. However, I don't understand what "normalization" serves for?

Comment: Could you give us some more context. May be it's in a context of `(lat,lon)->Text` transformation. In such case, it's about word order, status parts (such as str. alley e.t.c) formatting, and so on.

Comment: @dkiselev: It's regarding Text->(lat,lon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with geocoding at [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com/articles/what-are-geocodes) and have not run into the term "normalization" in reference to geocoding. My first inclination is that it could more likely refer to "standardization". In other words, normalization in the context of geocoding could mean cleaning the data and putting it into a standard or expected format. This standard or expected format would depend entirely on whatever application or service that is handling the data.